# Why does liquid {%SEO%} tag not get integrated into head? instead it shows in body

Tags: jekyll, liquid, head, document-body

For some unknown reason any LIQUID syntax used inside `<head>` ends up in the `<body>`

**What I have done?**

1) I cloned a template and build my own layout with JEKYLL static site generator.
2) I installed all gems (check gemlist: `'jekyll-seo-tag'` `'liquid 4.0'`)
3) I configured `config.yml`
4) I added `{%SEO%}` to `<head>`

**Minimal**

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Gino Ludikhuyze">
  <meta name="description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: 160 }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Title -->

  <title>title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>

  {% seo %}

</head>
```

**What is happening?**

If I render the website, online or local host, It shows a white GAP at the top. If I inspect it. It shows my liquid TAG in the body.

[image]

**What I expect to happen?**

That liquid should work in cohesion with jekyll.

**Link to repo:** https://github.com/bomengeduld/reno 
**Link to website:** https://bomengeduld.github.io/reno/

Comment: Head can't contain text. I'm assuming some preprocessor should handle that tag and it shouldn't be in the output at all.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: My situation is not easy to put into a fiddle @Quentin

Comment: LIquid syntax is supposed to integrated into the head @SamiKuhmonen Kuhmonen 

So not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: @GinoJanLudikhuyze — If you can't do the work to reduce your problem to a manageable size, why should *everyone* who tries to help you? Create a [mcve].

Comment: you are saying i should show the code inside the question?

Comment: @GinoJanLudikhuyze — Yes, that's what "in the question itself" means.

Comment: My apologies for any un easy way of putting my question. Is it better like this?

Comment: @GinoJanLudikhuyze — There seems to be a bunch of HTML that isn't needed to demonstrate the problem (see "minimal") and you're lacking the code where you define the value of `seo` and pass it into your template (see "complete")

Comment: I am complete novice into this. 

I have no idea how to reproduce the situation,

Since a few factors are involved, and these factors can only be shown in a repo, not a fiddle.

Comment: I tried to minify it as much as possible. Again, my apologies. But it would be helpfull, to know why liquid is not integrated. I have been searching and cant find anything about it.

This is not my first project. SO i am clueless.

Thanks for looking into this

Comment: @Quentin is my question good enough now?

Its not a clear html issue, If it was, i would reproduce the problem with a fiddle. This has more to do with how liquid gets rendered by jekyll.

Comment: Which branch is published by github pages (master or gh-pages) ?

Comment: master. But even in local host I have the same issue. 

It is strange, with any previous project, I didn't had any issues.

I followed any protocol for installing the jekyll seo plugin.

Still, the liquid syntax is seen as normal text, and thus is left in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index.html should start with (empty frontmatter):

```
---
---
```

Otherwise the Liquid will not get rendered. That is all!

Comment: I downloaded the repo, ran it, and fixed it in 5 seconds flat. You did all you could here. Great work/good question.

Comment: Sometimes you download a repo with a more conservative achitecture, so it's good to know that liquid only works when frontmatter is used in index.html. Great lesson learned here. 

Thanks Joost

Answer (score 0):

In Gemfile, add following line

```
gem "jekyll-seo-tag"
```

then `bundle install`