# Jekyll Mobile view "partly" not rendering, after yaml-front-matter was added to index.html

Tags: html, css, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

**Problem?**

For some reason the first section below header (it is a "mobile friendly" website) is not being rendered in mobile view. It remains blanco.

It is only a small part of the CSS, so It's not a obvious CSS issue either.

[image]

**What I have done?**

1) Cloned a template and build my own layout with JEKYLL static site generator.
2) This template had a classic rootdirectory (`css` + `index.html` file). 
3) I added `{% SEO%}` tag to `<head>` 
4) I encountered an issue described here [Why does liquid {%SEO%} tag not get integrated into head? instead it shows in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495210/why-does-liquid-seo-tag-not-get-integrated-into-head-instead-it-shows-in-bo) 
5) I added yaml-front-matter to `index.html` to solve the issue, but also changed the rootdirectory to a jekyll architecture (`_includes` + `_layouts` + frontmatter in `index.html` 
6) At the same time I attempted to reduce http requests by minifying the many css files into 1 file. 
7) After I discovered the issue with the mobile view not being rendered I changed everything back to classic. **Yet the problem remains.**

**Minimal**

```
---
---

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#primary-menu">
{{ content }}
    </body>
</html>
```

**What I expect to happen?**

That after adding yaml-front-matter, my mobile friendly website is rendered perfectly.

[image]

**Link to responsive.css:** https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamers/blob/master/css/responsive.css 
**Link to style.css:** https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamers/blob/master/style.css 
**Link to index.html:** https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamers/blob/master/index.html 
**Link to website:** https://bomengeduld.github.io/debadkamers/

Comment: Cannot reproduce this problem on laptop. Seems to be a css / browser compatibility problem.

Comment: its not a problem on laptop, its a problem on mobile

Comment: It is strange, because earlier it did showed on my mobile. So what could be the issue?

Comment: I just looked at your site on my mobile Chrome and Safari browsers, and I had to scroll past the section so the Javascript would trigger to bring the text in. It looks like you may be using an animation that hides the text initially and then swoops it in from the left. You may want to disable that script on mobile.

Comment: After looking at your site I am pretty sure @MaxGardner has found the key to the solution of your problem.